# Mapping from Sound Pressure To Frequency Domain

Tags: infrasound

I have a gem infrasound recorder which samples a pressure transducer. The raw data I get back is the sound pressure. I admittedly don't know what that means, but I do know I need to find out how to obtain the frequency spectrum given this information. Is there a mapping from sound pressure to frequency which would allow me to produce a typical waveform plot showing amplitude?

P.S. if you have a python reference for doing so that would be great!

Comment: I believe you are somewhat mixing the terms "spectrum", "pressure" and "waveform". The time variation of the pressure is actually the waveform and it's frequency representation (Fourier Transform as stated in some of the answers) is the spectrum. So, if you want to plot the waveform just plot the pressure values you get and if you want to plot the spectrum perform an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) and plot the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sound pressure, read amplitude (I know that is a simplification, but it will work for this) - all you need is a fast fourier transform from time domain to frequency doamin taking the amplitude data in over time, and voila.

Helpfully, iPython Interactive Computing and Visualization Cookbook has a [chapter on this available online using scipy.fftpack](https://ipython-books.github.io/101-analyzing-the-frequency-components-of-a-signal-with-a-fast-fourier-transform/) - the key commands are the fft() and fftfreq() functions

Also worth looking at [scipy-lectures example](http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy.html#fast-fourier-transforms-scipy-fftpack)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your data is indeed sound pressure in units of Pascal, then it’s relatively easy.  You can use [python-acoustics](https://github.com/python-acoustics/python-acoustics) to read the acoustic pressure data and plot the spectrum using [plot_power_spectrum](http://python-acoustics.github.io/python-acoustics/_modules/acoustics/_signal.html#Signal.plot_power_spectrum) method. Alternatively you can look into amplitude spectrum.

The key point is that python-acoustics treats values as an acoustic pressure rather than digital samples.

I imagine that your pressure values are sampled at equal intervals and you know the sampling frequency.